# ERC721A - Strings for uint256 | ERROR REMIX IDE

Tags: solidity, remix, erc-721

I'm struggling with this error, the contract is from a famous Blockchain Dev Youtuber **Hashlips** and i've used it months ago without error, but now when i put it **into REMIX Ide it gives me this error**.

Someone could help me?

**ERC721A Contract:**
https://github.com/hashlips-lab/nft-erc721-collection/blob/main/smart-contract/contracts/YourNftToken.sol

```
from solidity:
DeclarationError: Identifier not found or not unique.
  --> contracts/YourNftToken.sol:13:9:
   |
13 |   using Strings for uint256;
   |         ^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says it cannot find where `Strings` is declared, I checked your repo and you are not importing that library from anywhere, to solve it just import the library `Strings`.

Comment: Tried to import Strings.sol from openzeppelin Library... now it gives this error:

TypeError: Function needs to specify overridden contracts "ERC721A" and "IERC721A".
  --> Nuivo.sol:80:59:
   |
80 |   function tokenURI(uint256 _tokenId) public view virtual override returns (string memory) {
   |                                                           ^^^^^^^^
Note: This contract: 
  --> erc721a/contracts/ERC721A.sol:32:1:
   |
32 | contract ERC721A is IERC721A {
   | ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
Note: This contract:....